# Magento: Installation issue in Ubuntu

Tags: magento, ubuntu

PHP & MySql configuration are :

```
**MySql**   
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server version: 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

**Web Server** 
Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
MySQL client version: 5.1.63
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
```

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 
When I tried to install Magento 1.7.0.0 I got following error message :

```
The requested URL /magento17/index.php/install/ was not found on this server.
```

Can somebody suggest me to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try to install from gui or root terminal?

Comment: It seems like misspelling problem. Would you please provide the listing of your document root folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are install from root terminal, you can use sandard debian commands for packages. You can try find reason why it is not installed correctly. First try to find dependencies and that  are installed correctly:

```
dpkg -s magento17 | grep Depends:
```

when you see the result try to find if all dependencies are installed in correct version like on this example:

```
dpkg -l  apache2.2-comm
```

if it is correct you will see answer like4 this:

```
ii  apache2.2-comm 2.2.16-6+squee Apache HTTP Server common files
```

If it is all correct installed than you should try to check if problem is in using correct relative link!

try to use

```
magento17/index.php/install/
```